# Set callback URL for iOS apps in an Express application

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have an Express app that signs the user into Google using passport-google-oauth20, with the callback route: `https://(hosturl)/auth/google/redirect`.

I am trying to use this route to call my app after logging in using a ASWebAuthenticationSession and then get it to dismiss itself. I have already set my URL scheme in info.plist.

So far I have tried

```
api.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(301).redirect('com.googleusercontent.apps.<client id>');
});
```

which sends me to `https://(hosturl)/auth/google/redirect/com.googleusercontent.apps.<client id>`,
and

```
api.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(301).redirect('../../../com.googleusercontent.apps.<client id>');
});
```

which sends me to `https://(hosturl)/com.googleusercontent.apps.<client id>`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, the redirect should be:

```
api.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
  res.status(301).redirect('com.googleusercontent.apps.<client id>://');
});
```

The final '://' allows Express to recognise it as an external.